# RSA Encryption and Decryption on Different Machines

Tags: c++, rsa, virtual-machine

I'm trying to implement really simple RSA algorithm in C++, and I didn't use openSSL function. I have 3 functions, **generateParameter**, **encryption**, and **decryption**. The task of each function is :

1. **generateParameter** function will generate two prime numbers (p and q), modulus (n), public exponent (e), and private exponent (d), and then write the n,e,and d into a file.
2. **encryption** function will read the parameter n and e, encrypt the message and then write in into file.
3. **decryption** function will read the parameter n and d, read the encrypted message and then decrypt it.

All this functions work well if I run it in one machine, but what if I want to run it on 2 different Virtual Machines? Run the encryption on VM1, send the encrypted message (e.g. by using send() function), and then decrypt it on VM2.

How can VM2 decrypts the message if the parameter n and d are not sent to VM2? These 2 parameters are generated by doing math calculation on the prime numbers (p and q), but I know I can't send the prime numbers.

That are my questions, I appreciate any helps.

Regards,

dulipat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't fully understand of how public key encryption works.

*Both* partners have to generate their own public/private key pair. Afterwards, you share the *public* keys (that is, M1 sends its public key to M2 and vice versa). In reality, there is the problem of key distribution and authentication, i.e. how do I know that a public key that says it belongs to John really belongs to John? But for your small example, you can ignore this at first.

Once both machines have the partner's public keys, you encrypt a message going from M1 to M2 using **M2**'s public key. M2 then decrypts it using its private key. Apply the same idea for the reverse direction.

That way, you never have to share any of the prime factors or the private keys (as you correctly noticed, doing that would completely break the security of the process).